# Convert two arrays into a dictionary in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Let's say I have two arrays of the same length:

```
names = ["Adam", "Bob", "Colin"]
ages = [14, 11, 16]
```

How could I produce the following dictionary?

```
people = ["Adam": 14, "Bob": 11, "Colin": 16]
```

Comment: Whats the problem arrays are ordered so check count iterate the smaller one and use I to create dict..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using **Swift 4**, you can use **[uniqueKeysWithValues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127165-init)** and **[zip](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip)**:

```
let names = ["Adam", "Bob", "Colin"]
let ages = [14, 11, 16]

let people = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(names, ages))

print(people) // ["Adam": 14, "Colin": 16, "Bob": 11]
```

Otherwise, you could just use [**zip**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) with a for loop:

```
let names = ["Adam", "Bob", "Colin"]
let ages = [14, 11, 16]

var people = [String: Int]()
for (name, age) in zip(names, ages) {
    people[name] = age
}

print(people) // ["Adam": 14, "Bob": 11, "Colin": 16]
```